# Is there a way in python to assign variables values from a line that's read in

Tags: python, shell, unix

Sorry if I'm making incorrect assumptions between python and unix shell scripting.  I'm still new to the language.  Hopefully I'll learn quickly.

I'm wondering if there's a equivalent line in python to assign values to variables like you can from unix shell script?

For example, we can do this in unix shell scripting:

```
for line in $(cat file)
do
   IFS=' ' read var1 var2 var3 <<< "$line"
   echo "$var1, $var2, $var3" >> outfile
done
```

and it breaks up the line by spaces and assigns everything up to the 1st space to var1, between the 1st space and 2nd space to var2, and everything after that to var3.

Can we do the same thing in python?  I think I found something for python but it's not working, probably b/c I don't know what I'm doing.  var2 and var3 gives me an out of range message and printing var1 shows the variable "line", except with all spaces removed.  Not sure if rstrip or split did something to the line.  In any case, thanks in advance for your help and for not laughing at me while I'm trying to learn python ;)

```
file = open('data.txt','r')
for line in file:
   line.rstrip()
   tokens = line.split(' ')
   var1 = tokens[0]
   var2 = tokens[1]
   var3 = tokens[2]
   outfile.write(var1 + "," + var2 + "," + var3)
```

Comment: Could you provide the contents of "data.txt"?

Comment: Aside: It's superfluous to assign unique variables to each index of `tokens` when you can simply refer to `tokens[0]`, `tokens[1]`, and `tokens[2]` when writing to your file.

Comment: Are you sure the line is actually split with spaces rather than, say, tabs? Because if there are no actual spaces, `line.split(' ')` will return a list of one element, which is the whole line. Which is exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Also, in general, don't say "gives me an out of range message"; paste the actual exception, with traceback. Even if none of that gobbledegook means anything to you, it often means something to the people who are trying to help. (Likely not in this case, but unless you actually understand the errors, don't assume they're useless.)

Comment: @jmu303: +1, and of course that also means he can do `outfile.write(','.join(tokens))` instead of repeating himself. (Assuming he's already got some other way of handling invalid input, or happens to want to handle it silently.)

Comment: As another aside: `line.rstrip()` doesn't do anything useful, because `rstrip()` does not modify the string, it returns a new string. (In fact, _nothing_ modifies a string in Python; they're immutable.) So, `line = line.rstrip()`, or `tokens = line.rstrip().split(' ')`, is what you want there. But either way, this isn't causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks to the community for your comments and replies. I don't know why but the snippet works now. The only thing I can think of is I had a bunch of debug lines and code commented/un-commented. Something that was commented/un-commented affected the snippet above. I can delete this question or the moderators can close this question since it's not an issue anymore. I'll try to be more careful when posting/asking in the future. Thanks again for your willingness to help me.

Comment: @abarnert, thx for the tip on rstrip.  I was following an example in my book and it didn't re-assign the value to another variable. It looked like it was in IDLE and after typing in the cmd, the value of the variable was displayed. Good to know =)

Comment: @jmu303 - i just wanted to keep the variables straight when i print them out. that and i need to process some of them so it makes it easier to keep track of when i know what it should be instead of token[n] and having to remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I stumbled across what I was looking for.  Hopefully this helps someone else too:

```
for line in fileOutput:
    var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7 = line.rstrip().split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, with the tuple unpacking syntax:

```
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
```

This can be used as follows:

```
with open('data.txt','r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
       line = line.rstrip()
       parts = line.split(' ')
       outfile.write(','.join(parts))  # now you don't have to worry about how many elements there are in each line
```

A couple of notes (since you self-identify as a beginner):

- don't name your variables `file` or `list` or `dict` or any other built-in type for that matter.
- See the `with` syntax I've used up there? That's called a context. It comes in very handy. This way, I don't have to close the file after opening it. The context manager takes care of that for me
- Notice that I did `line = line.rstrip()`. That's because `rstrip()` returns a string, without altering the original.

Comment: As an aside: In Python 3.x, `file` isn't a built-in type or constructor; in 2.x, it is, but you're discouraged from referring to it. So, this isn't nearly as bad as using `list` or `dict` for a variable name.

Comment: But meanwhile, this is all good advice, and nicely explained to boot… but none of his solves his problem (which appears to be that his `line.split(' ')` is returning a list of only 1 element), so it's really not an answer.

Comment: @abarnert: I hadn't noticed that before. Check out the edit please

Comment: I don't think the edit solves his problem either. He clearly believes that every line in his file has exactly 2 spaces, and yet they almost certainly have _no_ spaces, or he wouldn't be getting those errors. Which means your code will just copy the original file unchanged, instead of raising an exception. (Really, until he actually gives us his data, I don't think it's possible for anyone to solve the problem, short of by wild guessing…)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll try to remember them when I code in python.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
test_str = "aaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee"    
tokens = test_str.split(' ')  
if len(tokens) > 3:  
  var1 = tokens[0]
  var2 = tokens[1]
  var3 = tokens[2:]
>>> print(var1, '+', var2, '+', var3)
    aaa + bbbb + ['cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee']
```

var3 is not a string, but I think you can change it to any format you want.:-)

Comment: What is this even intended to solve? He's getting an `IndexError` on `var2 = tokens[1]`. Your code will raise the exact same `IndexError`. The fact that he's ignoring any tokens beyond the third doesn't seem too important given that he expects only three tokens, and actually gets only one.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

with open('data.txt','r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        tokens = line.split()
        assert len(tokens) == 3
        fieldname1, fieldname2, fieldname3 = tokens
        outfile.write('{}.{}.{}\n'.format(fieldname1, fieldname1, fieldname3))
```

This runs on 2.7 or 3.3 with no changes.

You should use more descriptive variable names than fieldname1, etc.

Comment: How does this solve anything? Either it just fails with an assertion instead of an `IndexError`, or it happens to get lucky for a reason you haven't explained.